# GMap.NET Windows Forms move the map with the mouse

Tags: winforms, mousemove, mousedown, gmap.net

How in GMapControl it is correct to handle pressing and moving Google maps using the mouse?

```
GMapControl gMap = new GMapControl();
gMap.MouseDown += GMap_MouseDown;

private void GMap_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    gMap.MouseMove += GMap_MouseMove;
}

private void GMap_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     base.OnMouseMove(e);
     //gMap.Position = new PointLatLng(X, Y);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any code to move the map.  The default is for the RIGHT mouse button to move the map, which I found rather awkward.  To change to the LEFT mouse, use code like this in the Load() event of your Form:

```
gMap.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left;
```